# Proof checking: $B\subseteq A$ implies $\sup B \leq \sup A$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, self-learning

Given  $B \subseteq A$. Assume $\sup B > \sup A$. Now $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists b\ \in B (b > \sup B - \epsilon)$. Take $\epsilon = \sup B- \sup A$. That is $\exists b\ \in B (b > \sup A)$.

Since $b$ also belongs to $A$. So we have found some element of $A$ which is bigger than its Supremum. Hence a contradiction.

Thanks

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Comment: Your proof is fine. Here is another: *Since $\sup A$ is greater than or equal to every element of $A$, then is also greater than or equal to every element of $B$; thus $\sup A$ is an upper bound for $B$, and then $\sup B \leq \sup A$.*

Comment: Thanks all.......

Comment: You must know the existence of $\sup A$ and $\sup B$ in order to prove your result. Example: if the studied poset is $\{1,2,3,4\}$ along with the partial order "divides", then the set $\{1,2,3\}$ is included in the set $\{1,2,3,4 \}$  but none of them has a $\sup$ (because the set of upper bounds of any of them is empty). Another example, this time with a totally ordered set: in the poset $(\mathbb Z , \leq)$, $\mathbb Z$ doesn't have a $\sup$.